# Lambda with two streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

Can I do this without doing two separate streams and without temporarily storing id's and statuses in a HashMap?

```
SaveStatus saveStatus = saveService.save(input);
Map<Long, SaveStatus> savedStatuses = new HashMap<>();
saveStatus.getSaveStatusResults()
    .stream()
    .forEach(s -> savedStatuses.put(s.getId(), s.getSavedStatus()));

objectToUpdateWithNewStatuses.getSaveInstructions()
    .stream()
    .map(SaveInstruction::getTransaction)
    .forEach(t -> t.setSaveStatus(savedStatuses.get(t.getId())));
```

Comment: provide `SaveStatus`, `SaveStatusResult`, `SaveInstruction ` as well

Comment: I think this is just fine logic: `savedStatuses` as mapping function from id to SaveStatus. Do not start with `objectToUpdateWithNewStatuses` using grouping on id, {id, set of transaction) and then feed it to `getSaveStatusResults` for `setSaveStatus`. That is uglier IMHO. Ideal would be if `getSaveStatusResults` would yield that map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using two distinct streams makes sense here!

The second stream doesn't take as input/source the map collected from the first stream, it needs that to perform fast retrieval.

But you could improve the first stream in this way:

```
Map<Long, SaveStatus> savedStatuses = 
saveStatus.getSaveStatusResults()
    .stream()
    .collect(toMap(SaveStatusResult::getId, SaveStatusResult::getSavedStatus));
```

The method references used suppose that `SaveStatus.getSaveStatusResults()` returns an `Collection` of `SaveStatusResult`.

And keep the second stream as it is defined.